# BigQuery Function to Persist Values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What is the best way to persist a value in BigQuery? For example, if the value in the cell is `(none)` then it should get the last known value that is not `(none)` but if the value then changes, begin persisting that value. See below for an example of what I'd like. I tried using the LAG function but it only works for one row.

```
Row      Value      Persisted
1        Apple      Apple
2        (none)     Apple
3        (none)     Apple
4        (none)     Apple
5        Orange     Orange
6        (none)     Orange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

To achieve your goal you need some extra field in your data that will define the order of your values  - usually it is column with timestamp,date,etc. data type, or number reflecting position. In below example I am using `ts` as a such column

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ts, value, 
  LAST_VALUE(IF(value = '(none)', NULL, value) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts) Persisted
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 ts, 'Apple' Value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '(none)' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '(none)' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '(none)' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Orange' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, '(none)'  
)
SELECT ts, value, 
  LAST_VALUE(IF(value = '(none)', NULL, value) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts) Persisted
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row ts  value   Persisted    
1   1   Apple   Apple    
2   2   (none)  Apple    
3   3   (none)  Apple    
4   4   (none)  Apple    
5   5   Orange  Orange   
6   6   (none)  Orange
```